# Skype unable to login on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, skype

One of my machines here - the only Windows PC - has three different Windows installations on it:

- Windows XP 32-bit, my current main installation
- Windows 7 public beta 32-bit, mainly installed this to try out Windows 7. It's got the basic tools on it that I normally use, but it's a plain vanilla install
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, just installed. This currently has only a handful of programs installed (FeedDemon, JDK + NetBeands, Skype) that I also have on the 32-bit install

All of the above installs have the same settings for TCP/IP - same IPv4 network address, netmask, default gateway and DNS servers. There is a firewall between me and the big bad Internet, but it's set up to let pretty much everything through from my side and does not affect Skype operation on the two 32-bit installations.

On both 32-bit installs, Skype can connect to the Internet fine and log me in without any issues. On 64-bit Win7, I am unable to log in and the error message I receive advises me to check my network connection. All three installs have the same version of Skype (latest Windows version), the Advanced->Connection settings are the same on all three also.

I'm pretty much stumped at this point in time. The only idea I have is to uninstall, redownload and reinstall Skype on the 64-bit Win7.

Has anybody here seen similar problems with running Skype on a 64-bit Windows 7 installation?

**UPDATE:** I've uninstalled Skype, downloaded the installer again and reinstalled Skype. It now appears to be able to connect and log in.

Comment: I had no problems running Skype on my 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype has issues with windows 7 and the new installer should fix it.

Comment: This seems to be the case, as the fresh installer cured the problem.

Comment: sure thing i had the same problem when i upgraded